# Colorings of a cube with an asymmetric image?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, group-actions, coloring, symmetry

I am attempting to figure out how many ways there are to draw the figure Z (or any rotation or reflection of it) on each of the six faces of a cube. That is, there are four possible labels for each face: Z, N, И, and mirrored Z.

When counting the number of labelings, any two cube-labelings that are related by a proper rotation of the cube should be considered identical.

The figure Z shares 180-degree rotational symmetry with the cube, and no other symmetry.

I am familiar with Burnside's counting lemma, and I have determined, for example, that if we ignored rotations of Z and instead just counted whether we were using [a rotation of] Z or its mirror image, we would have 10 possible combinations.

But I do not know how to extend this counting procedure in the case where the labels we're assigning to faces also have their own symmetry properties.  I wrote a computer program to count them and got 216, but there is always a possibility I made a mistake --- I would much rather know formally how to prove it.

Comment: Can you clarify your problem? There are only two colors, say red and black, right? Each square can either feature a red `Z` be painted on black or a black `Z` painted on red? And reflections (even that cannot happen in physical $3$-space are allowed, e.g. one that turns a `N` into a `И`) are allowed?

Comment: @SammyBlack Fixed! I removed the analogy with red/black colors.  You're counting the number of rotationally distinct ways of labeling each face with Z or any rotation/reflection of it --- one of four possibilities: Z, N, И, and mirrored Z.

Comment: Okay, but it's still not clear to me which version of the problem you're asking. You write "rotationally distinct" both here in the comments and in the post, but then you speak of reflections. Note: there are $4! = 24$ distinct rotational symmetries of a cube in $3$-space, but there are twice as many distinct symmetries if reflections are allowed (these orientation-reversing symmetries require the cube to be turned inside out). Without reflections, `N` will never turn into a `И`.

Comment: Okay, I've reread your edited post and comment again. I think I understand. Can you confirm? You are only considering rotations of the cube (a.k.a. *proper* rotations) but the labels on the faces might be mirror images of one-another, hence cannot be rotated one into the other.

Comment: @SammyBlack. Yes, that's right!  Only proper rotations of the cube, and the face labels might be mirror images of one another, hence cannot be rotated one onto the other.
In other words, I am trying to count the number of ways of labeling each face of the cube with one of the four possibilities {Z, N, И, and mirrored Z}, where any two labelings that are related through a proper rotation of the cube itself should be considered indistinguishable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are $6$ faces on the cube and $4$ distinct *labelings* of each face, there are initially $4^6 = 4096$ labelings. We now have to let the group of symmetries of the cube act on it by *proper* rotations and enumerate the orbits.

As you mentioned, according Burnside (really Frobenius or Cauchy), we have to consider the fixed-set for each of the $|S_4| = 4! = 24$ elements of the permutation group of the cube, which we can organize by conjugacy class:

- the identity element fixes all $4^6$ labelings
- six $90^\circ$ face rotations each fix $0$ labelings
- three $180^\circ$ face rotations each fix $4^4$ labelings
- eight $120^\circ$ vertex rotations each fix $4^2$ labelings
- six $180^\circ$ edge rotations each fix $4^3$ labelings.

This looks very similar to the calculation when we are coloring the faces from a palette with $4$ colors explained in great detail [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Burnside%27s_lemma#Colorings_of_a_cube), with one important difference: whereas a $90^\circ$ face rotation allows an independent choice of any color on either of the two faces pierced by the rotation axis and any *single* choice of color for the other $4$ faces, hence $4^3$ possibilities, in the present problem none of the labelings are fixed by a $90^\circ$ rotation.

Therefore, the total count is
$$
\frac{4^6 + 3\cdot 4^4 + 6\cdot 4^3 + 8\cdot 4^2}{24} = 224
$$
distinct labelings.

Comment: Thanks very much! I want to make sure I'm counting the orbits correctly. If in another problem I extend the group of allowed symmetries to the full 48, for example, then I think none of the improper rotations preserve anything, except the reflected edge rotations which preserve 4^3 labelings each. Am I counting things correctly?